# rails drop down to select the years from current year to past four years

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, drop-down-menu

How do I create a drop down with a list of years beginning from current year and 4 years backward (2015, 2014... 2013)? and by default it should show the current year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agreed with Pavan but this would be much better

```
<%= select_year(Date.today, :start_year => Date.today.year, :end_year =>  Date.today.year-4) %>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [***`select_year`***](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/select_year). Something like below will do

```
<%= select_year(Date.today, :start_year => Date.today.year, :end_year => 2012) %>
```